# iphone distrubution certificate problem

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store, distribution

i have a little problem in submission my app, and i have a little question that i can't find the answer,

When i develop an app, i create a certificate, and i finished up my app, i wanna submit it to app store. To atchive my goal, i should change some of the app plist info, so what should i have to change to submit my app to app store correctly. and where i should change other than plist info,

i have to fill this info, so what should i write on it:
1. Bundle display name:
2. Executable file:
3. Bundle identifier:
4. Bundle name:

and the problem that when i create an app ID in apple portal , i do not know where i must put this id in my app plist and other places.

Any advice :)

Comment: it seems no body here :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Bundle Display Name** is the application name which will be displayed with app. icon on iPhone screen.
2. **Executable File** not necessary; leave it as it is.
3. **Bundle Identifier** is the App. Id which you used to create provisioning profile.
4. **Bundle Name** is the name of executable file name; changing it is not necessary, by default project name is used.

For more information and guidelines please visit

https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?appIdKey=D635F5C417E087A3B9864DAC5D25920C4E9442C9339FA9277951628F0291F620&path=//appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: hi waqas raja ...
thanks for answer but i would to ask you where the other places i must fill it before the distribution and where the other places i must put the App ID in it?

Comment: @Adel Jodalah, hi only the Bundle Identifier (to fill in APP ID) is required for distribution, follow these guidelines provided by apple https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Comment: thanks again ,you answer is correct BUT if i can, i need to ask you another question ..that
if i have an individual apple account (99$/year) and this account register with my name BUT can i add an app to app-store with out display my real name ??
i.e i would really to know if i can add app with a nickname or something like thins , i do not need to display my real name in app-store because some issue  
tell me if you now or if you do not know redirect me to some where that i can find the answer :)